# How to get the list of slow executing tasks?

Tags: sql-server, qsqlquery

[Schems DataBase](http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app#agdkYmRzZ25ycg8LEgZTY2hlbWEY0tneAww)
Example Report:

Task_**__|_Percent_Executing**|_Executing_0f_day_|**Header**|

Task_1   |   20               | 12               | Трудягин Т.Т. |

Task_2   |   90               | 7                | Исполнительный И.И. |

Task_3   |   50               | 7                | Трудягин Т.Т. |

**
To perform their duties, responsible for monitoring must identify tasks that other relatively too slow run. To do this, responsible for overseeing the report should be made available, including 10 (or less) for the slow-running task.**

```
SELECT TOP 10 ta.problemStatement AS N'Задача',
    --emp.firstName AS N'Исполнитель',
    DATEDIFF(dd,MIN(startDate),MAX(startDate)) AS N'Количество дней',
    MAX(percent100) AS N'Процент',
    MAX(startDate)/*,
    (SELECT firstName FROM Version AS ve INNER JOIN Employee AS emp
       ON ve.id_employee_leader = emp.id 
     WHERE ve.startDate IN (MAX(startDate)))*/
FROM 
  Version AS ve INNER JOIN Task AS ta
    ON ve.id_task = ta.id   
  INNER JOIN Employee AS emp
    ON emp.id = ve.id_employee_leader
  WHERE emp.id <= 15    
GROUP BY ta.problemStatement 
ORDER BY 2 DESC
GO
```